# Multiple teams share same User Story!

Tags: agile, devops

I have a project that will be handled by more than one platform: Web - ios - android
There is a team for each platform.
All teams will share the same User stories.

For example:
The same "Login" user story will be checked by the 3 teams and done in different sprints.

I want to save time adding different User stories for each platform.(Web - IOS - Android)

What is the best way to handle this in Agile (Azure DevOps)?

Can I do something like substories for each story?
Can someone suggest a solution?

(Please, keep in mind that I don't have to add different requirements for each team or platform.
That can be handled in Tasks items).

Comment: Please share an example of an actual user story. I'm downvoting this because it lacks sufficient detail, but will happily retract my downvote if you update your question with meaningful detail. For example, without seeing what you think a "login" user story looks like, it's really hard to understand why you think: 1) this is a user story and not a task, and 2) why you think the "story" should be identical across multiple teams.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Azure DevOps, but I assume they have the concept of [Epic](https://www.agilealliance.org/epic-confusion/) available. You should be able to have a common "login" Epic with different Stories for each Platform.

You'd keep the core of the requirements at the Epic level (to avoid duplication) and then the Stories (or tasks) required for each platform linked to this Epic.

Comment: This is something I can do. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the SAME user story but 3 comparable stories

- As a Web user ....
- As an IOS user ....
- As an android user ....

Probably also

- As multi plaform user I want same user experience on all platform.

INVEST your stories => INDEPENDANT

---

A troll approach is "if you need to keep all in ONE story (even it's splitted in many subtask), so that ONE agile team"

- All the AGILE team is responsible of all the stories

  - Not everybody has same skills, but everybody is responsible
- An AGILE team has no depedency with another team to achieve items (stories) of the sprint backlog
- An story is (invesT=>) timeboxed, and can be DONE in ONE sprint (if  not => That's a epic to split in many stories)

---

To read:
==> search on web "component teams vs feature teams"

You describe a structure with "component team".

If you progress to feature team, your problem disappears.